# Can i pass a class into a function within the same class on Swift (Trying to write a class that was written using C++ with the Swift Language)

Tags: c++, swift, class

I created a a program to do some of my calculations on C++ a while ago and I'm trying to do the same basic program with Swift as a way to start learning the language (Swift) but XCode keeps giving me errors regarding the variables from the array I am trying to access. Basically I am trying to access a variable from an array of the class I am creating inside the class itself. I'm really not that good at explaining but ill show you the C++ class I'm trying to recreate using swift:

```
class investors {
    string name = " "; //Name of Investor
    double investment = 0; // Amount Invested
    double last_total = 0; // current total value of all investments(execluding this investment) just before adding the investment.
    double percent = 0; // Percentage

    public:
    // Set and Get Functions for Values
    void set_name(string new_name)             {name = new_name;}
    void set_investment(double new_investment) {investment = new_investment;}
    void set_last_total(double new_last_total) {last_total = new_last_total;}
    void set_percent(double new_percent)       {percent = new_percent;}

    string get_name()       {return name;}
    double get_investment() {return investment;}
    double get_last_total() {return last_total;}
    double get_percent()    {return percent;}

    void recalc_percent(vector <investors> &old_investors) { // Function that recalculates all previous percentage to account for the added investment
        for (int i = 0; i < old_investors.size(); i++) {
            double temp_percent = old_investors.at(i).get_percent();
            temp_percent = (temp_percent * last_total) / (last_total + investment);
            old_investors.at(i).set_percent(temp_percent);
        }
    }

    void calc_percent(vector <investors> &old_investors) { // Calculating Newly added percentage of investment added 
        percent = (investment / (investment + last_total)) * 100;
        recalc_percent(old_investors);
    }

    double current_amount(double final_amount) { // Returns how much investor currently has in US Dollars
        return (percent * final_amount) / 100;
    }
};
```

and this is where I am at using swift:

```
class Investors {
    var name: String
    var investment = 0.0
    var lastTotal = 0.0
    var percent = 0.0

    init(name: String, investment: Double, lastTotal: Double, percent: Double) {
        self.name = name
        self.investment = investment
        self.lastTotal = investment
        self.percent = percent
    }

    func recalc_percent(oldInvestors: [Investors]) {   
        for (people) in oldInvestors {
            var tempPercent = oldInvestors[people].percent // This is where my issue is.
        }
    }

    func calc_percent(oldInvestors: [Investors]){
        percent = (investment / (investment + lastTotal)) * 100 //I had an error over here as well.
    }
}
```

What are the limitations on Swift? I am thinking that those limitations would mean that i have to write the program in a different way than how it is in the C++ version.

Edit: the first error in the swift code (I commented next to the code where there is an error happening) gives me this message : Cannot subscript a value of type `[Investors]` with an index of type `Investors`.

I will add the second error message in a bit.

Comment: Your question title doesn't seem to match your body question, please edit to make it more obvious what you're actually asking.

Comment: Hi @aimen, you should also try to make a [mcve], and show the errors that you are getting. This will help other people to help you, and make your question more useful to others in future. Welcome to SO.

Comment: Will do, Thank you for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seems to not fully understand how for loops in swift work. In a for loop like this:

```
for (people) in oldInvestors{

}
```

`people` here would contain a reference (pointer) to each element in the array each iteration. In other words, the variable `people` here is actually similar to `old_investors.at(i)` in the C++ code.

This is why using `people` as the subscript does not work.

I have translated the rest of the code for you:

```
class Investors{

    var name: String
    var investment = 0.0
    var lastTotal = 0.0
    var percent = 0.0

    init(name: String, investment: Double, lastTotal: Double, percent: Double) {
        self.name = name
        self.investment = investment
        self.lastTotal = investment
        self.percent = percent
    }

    func recalc_percent(oldInvestors: [Investors]){

        for investor in oldInvestors{
            var tempPercent = investor.percent
            investor.percent = (tempPercent * lastTotal) / (lastTotal + investment)

        }


    }

    func calc_percent(oldInvestors: [Investors]){
        percent = (investment / (investment + lastTotal)) * 100 

        recalc_percent(oldInvestors: oldInvestors)
    }

    func currentAmount(finalAmount: Double) -> Double {
        return (percent * finalAmount) / 100
    }
}
```

Though what you are trying to do is quite weird...

I suggest you to read everything on Apple's [Swift Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/) first, then write some swift programs yourself and get into the swift mindset before translating code.

Comment: Thanks Alot! I have gone through a small portion of it, but thought I could start doing something simple, I tend to learn alot faster after doing something versus before.

Comment: @aimenalt If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Comment: to calculate and recalculate how much money and percent each person invested into a investment pot fund. say imagine someone invested 5000 then that grew into 6000 and then someone else invested 5000, both invested equally but the earlier guy had his money already grown a bit. so my main issue was everytime a new investor was added i had to recalculate every single person's current amount/increases and percentage. it became a headache and reached the point it took me 2 hours to recalculate when another person was added. so i created a program that would do the recalculations for me